# Error while creating an attribute group in Contact builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, contactbuilder, attribute-group

We are getting an error as follows when we are creating a relationship between attribute group and a data extension in Contact builder. We are using a sendable and testable DE to link with this new Attribute group. Using subscriber key of DE to map with contactKey of attribute group. We tried refreshing by clearing cache but to no avail

> An error occurred attempting to refresh the data model. Refresh the page, and contact Global Support for additional assistance regarding this error.

[image]

Comment: It appears there was an issue today with Contact builder, I would suggest trying again

Comment: @EazyE : Yes, it started working after some time. Such a weird behavior is expected from marketing cloud.

Answer (score 0):

This is old I know but I found the error, our DE had a weird character in the name which is what fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

To add, it seems Contact Builder does not like "+" in SubscriberKey (or the Primary Key email address field). I removed the email record with the "+" and it resolved the error.

Comment: CORRECTION:  It was because I had 2 SFMC tabs open.